# What vehicle has the highest number of modificable parts?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

On Grand Theft Auto V and Online, the vehicles can have the following parts modified:

- LSC: Spoiler, Front Bumper, Rear Bumper, Side Skirt, Exhaust, Frame, Grille, Hood, Left Fender, Right Fender, Roof, Engine, Brakes, Transmission, Horns, Suspension, Armor, Front Wheels, Back Wheels
- Benny's: Plate Frame, Vanity Plate, Trim, Ornaments, Dashboard, Dials, Door Speaker, Seats, Steering Wheel, Shift Levers, Plaques, Speakers, Trunk, Hydraulics, Engine Block, Air Filter, Struts, Arch Cover, Aerials, Trim, Tank, Windows, Livery

What vehicle has the highest number of modificable parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking purely overall? One category you left out is [Arena War](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Vehicles_in_GTA_Online:_Arena_War) vehicles (only modifiable in your Arena workshop).

Among these, I'd have to say the one with the most available options would be the [Nightmare Issi](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Nightmare_Issi) (though I believe Future Shock and Apocalypse flavors have similar options).  Fully loaded, you can easily dump $4-5 million into your customized Issi.

From a Benny's standpoint, there seems to be a [consensus that the Sultan](https://gtaforums.com/topic/852203-which-car-is-the-best-one-at-bennys/) is the most customizable.

I'm really not sure on the regular LSC vehicles - they all seem to have about the same set of options, some a couple more than others, but all in about the same range.